# I want to get records from BigQuery table which has atleast one of the two needed value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My BigQuery Schema has suppose 
`company_name | email | email_2 | phone | mobile |`and there are about 50K records into the table.
I want to fetch records that at least have mention of a phone number and email.
Needs rows with 
eg. 
`email phone`
`email mobile`
`email_2 phone` 
`email_2 mobile`
`email email_2 phone`
`email email_2 phone mobile`

What's the efficient code for this, as i am new to both SQL and BigQuery?

```
FROM Property_Dataset.pmDATA 
WHERE 
(email IS NOT NULL AND phone IS NOT NULL) OR
(email IS NOT NULL AND mobile IS NOT NULL) OR
(email_2 IS NOT NULL AND phone IS NOT NULL) OR
(email_2 IS NOT NULL AND mobile IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: Can you try::> 

where (email is not null or email_2 is not null) AND (phone is not null or mobile is not null)

Comment: it was for big-query database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below is most compact and scalable (in terms of number of involved columns) - for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.Property_Dataset.pmDATA`
WHERE NOT COALESCE(email, email_2) IS NULL
AND NOT COALESCE(phone, mobile) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use a where clause like below:

```
select *
from Property_Dataset.pmDATA 
where (email is not null or email_2 is not null) AND (phone is not null or mobile is not null)
```